# Options regarding public end point security

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'd like to create a static AWS S3 hosted webpage ... the page would consist of a simple HTML5 textbox for user generated comments. A user could then input a comment via this input, press a submit button, which would push data to an AWS server using async. Javascript callbacks.

The AWS server would accept the input, and every 15 minutes, update a static file (the new comments) within an S3 bucket.

I'm doing this because I don't want to incur database costs to retrieve messages, when I can use a delayed process like what's described above.

My concern however is security. Is there any creative way to limit a user from posting a million comments because I'm not requiring a login. I thought I'd limit comments by IP address so that if more than 10 comments were posted in any 60 minute window, the server would discard them, but this doesn't work w/large proxies. Based on the above configuration, what options do I have? I genuinely am at a loss because all the data you could filter on (a cookie, a user agent string, etc.) can be spoofed. Am I missing anything notable?

Answer (score 0):

You are struggling with a two major problems... ***brute force*** and ***denial of service***. As you said all the data that could be saved for identification on the user's browser could be spoofed. Even complicated thing such as [CSRF Tokens](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)) can't help you. Also, the idea with IP addresses identification is pretty drastic. *What will happen if I spoof my IP address and start sending packets without any care about their return?* This way I could block a lot of other IP address and you will deny access to someone who needs it. It is not a solution.

So back to the question, ***No***, there is no way to defend yourself without any authentication. You are gonna either be denying service to people because you limit the amount of request or they are gonna flood you and you will once again deny service.

Good luck.